# Runtime Error when running Angular 4 app via `ng serve`

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I have a Spring Boot project that uses Angular on the frontend. I recently upgraded my project from Angular 2 to Angular 4. Both before and after the upgrade, I can build and run my application and it runs perfectly fine when it's bundled as a war and I run it on my tomcat server.

However, when developing frontend changes, I would run the frontend separately via the angular cli command, `ng serve`. When I was on Angular 2, that was working perfectly fine. Now that I'm on Angular 4, when I run the application via `ng serve`, I get the following error in the developer console when I try to load the application in a browser.

```
Uncaught Error: Unexpected value '[object Object]' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.
    at syntaxError (compiler.es5.js:1690) [<root>]
    at :4200/vendor.bundle.js:99805:44 [<root>]
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.es5.js:15365) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.es5.js:26795) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.es5.js:26768) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp.../../../compiler/@angular/compiler.es5.js.JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (compiler.es5.js:26697) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (core.es5.js:4536) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_.webpackJsonp.../../../core/@angular/core.es5.js.PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (core.es5.js:4522) [<root>]
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (main.ts:11) [<root>]
    at Object.0 (main.ts:11) [<root>]
```

Any ideas as to why it would build and run perfectly fine in production mode, but receives the above error when running via `ng serve`?

Here is my `app.module.ts`:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {MaintenanceModule} from "./maintenance/maintenance.module";
import {MyCommonModule} from "my-web-common-angular";
import {CoreModule} from "./core/core.module";
import {NotificationService} from "./core/notification.service";
import {ManagementModule} from "./management/management.module";
import {RegisteredDevicesModule} from "./registered-devices/registered-devices.module";
import {NotificationInboxModule} from "./notification-inbox/notification-inbox.module";
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from "@angular/platform-browser/animations";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: "", redirectTo: "manage", pathMatch: "full"},
      {path: "**", redirectTo: "manage", pathMatch: "full"},
    ]),
    CoreModule,
    MaintenanceModule,
    ManagementModule,
    RegisteredDevicesModule,
    NotificationInboxModule,
    MyCommonModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [NotificationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**UPDATE:** If I run `ng serve --prod` it gets past the error and the application actually loads. But I don't want to run it in `--prod` mode, because I have different settings specific to running it locally in my `environment.ts` files, and the app won't load data properly without those settings.

**EDIT:** As requested, here is `MyCommonModule` from `my-web-common-angular` dependency:

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }  from '@angular/forms';

import { HeaderComponent } from './src/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './src/footer/footer.component';
import {HierarchySelectComponent} from './src/hierarchy/hierarchy-select.component';
import {HierarchySelectDialogComponent} from './src/hierarchy/hierarchy-select-dialog.component';
import {TreeModule} from 'primeng/components/tree/tree';
import {DialogModule} from  'primeng/components/dialog/dialog';
import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/components/button/button';
import {InputTextModule} from "primeng/components/inputtext/inputtext";
import { MessagesModule} from 'primeng/components/messages/messages';

export * from './src/header/header.component';
export * from './src/footer/footer.component';
export * from './src/hierarchy/hierarchy-select.component';
export * from './src/hierarchy/hierarchy-select-dialog.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    TreeModule,
    DialogModule,
    ButtonModule,
    InputTextModule,
    MessagesModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HierarchySelectComponent,
    HierarchySelectDialogComponent
  ],
  exports: [
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    HierarchySelectComponent,
    HierarchySelectDialogComponent
  ]
})
export class MyCommonModule {
  public static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
    return {
      ngModule: MyCommonModule
    };
  }
}
```

And the other modules from my project.

`maintenance.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {NotificationListComponent} from "./notification-list.component";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {SharedModule} from "primeng/components/common/shared";
import {DataTableModule} from "primeng/components/datatable/datatable";
import {NotificationEditComponent} from "./notification-edit.component";
import {FieldsetModule} from "primeng/components/fieldset/fieldset";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {GrowlModule} from "primeng/components/growl/growl";
import {TooltipModule} from "primeng/components/tooltip/tooltip";
import {ConfirmDialogModule} from "primeng/components/confirmdialog/confirmdialog";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotificationListComponent,
    NotificationEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: "maintenance/list", component: NotificationListComponent},
      {path: "maintenance/edit/:id", component: NotificationEditComponent},
      {path: "maintenance/edit", component: NotificationEditComponent}
    ]),
    SharedModule,
    DataTableModule,
    FieldsetModule,
    GrowlModule,
    TooltipModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule
  ]
})
export class MaintenanceModule {}
```

`management.module.ts`

```
import {GrowlModule} from "primeng/components/growl/growl";
import {FieldsetModule} from "primeng/components/fieldset/fieldset";
import {SharedModule} from "primeng/components/common/shared";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {NotificationManageComponent} from "./notification-manage.component";
import {NotificationSelectComponent} from "./notification-select.component";
import {TooltipModule} from "primeng/components/tooltip/tooltip";
import {MessagesModule} from "primeng/primeng";
import {RegistrationService} from "./registration.service";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotificationManageComponent,
    NotificationSelectComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: "manage", component: NotificationManageComponent},
      {path: "manage/:userId", component: NotificationManageComponent}
    ]),
    SharedModule,
    FieldsetModule,
    GrowlModule,
    MessagesModule,
    TooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [
    RegistrationService
  ]
})
export class ManagementModule {
}
```

`notification-inbox.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {DialogModule, GrowlModule, SharedModule, TooltipModule} from "primeng/primeng";
import {NotificationInboxComponent} from "./notification-inbox.component";
import {NotificationMessageComponent} from "./notification-message.component";
import {NotificationInboxService} from "./notification-inbox.service";
import {PaginationComponent} from "./pagination.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    NotificationInboxComponent,
    NotificationMessageComponent,
    PaginationComponent
  ],
  imports:[
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: "inbox", component: NotificationInboxComponent}
    ]),
    SharedModule,
    GrowlModule,
    TooltipModule,
    DialogModule
  ],
  providers: [
    NotificationInboxService
  ]
})
export class NotificationInboxModule {
}
```

`registered-devices.module.ts`

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import {FormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {CommonModule} from "@angular/common";
import {RouterModule} from "@angular/router";
import {GrowlModule, SharedModule, TooltipModule} from "primeng/primeng";
import {RegisteredDevicesComponent} from "./registered-devices.component";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RegisteredDevicesComponent
  ],
  imports:[
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: "registered-devices", component: RegisteredDevicesComponent}
    ]),
    SharedModule,
    GrowlModule,
    TooltipModule
  ],
  providers: [
  ]
})
export class RegisteredDevicesModule {}
```

Comment: Do as the error message says: check that all the modules you're importing are decorated with NgModule.

Comment: @JBNizet all of my custom modules have the `@NgModule` decorator. None of the angular modules do though - `BrowserModule`, `HttpModule`, etc.

Comment: What version of `primeng` are you using?

Comment: @KirkLarkin 4.1.3

Comment: `my-web-common-angular` uses `primeng` 4.0.0 though. Could those conflicting versions be a problem?

Comment: I think it's a conflict like that somewhere. `primeng` 4.0.0 is very old, so I'm thinking it's likely the issue. I'm going to assume you've upgraded Angular in in `my-web-common-angular` to v4 too. This link might be helpful: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15763.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Actually the `my-web-common-angular` has semantic versioning. The `@angular` dependencies are `^4.1.0` and `primeng` is `^4.0.0`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154807/discussion-between-kirk-larkin-and-andrew-mairose).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments and further discussion in chat, this was discovered to be a conflict between the version of `primeng` being used in the newly upgraded project and the version being used in `my-web-common-angular`. Simply upgrading `primeng` in `my-web-common-angular` resolved the conflict.